# How to exclude my start search word and end search word in my regex result while trying to find words in sentence ocurring between 2 words

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

```
st = "i ordered a book and it was delivered  to my office  HHHH address  instead of the home ZZZ address  today"

re.search(rf'office(.*?)address|home(.*?)address',st).group(0)

output:'office  HHHH address'
```

How to exclude my start  search term(office) and end search terms (address) in my result ,i tried many things but it did nto work ,can you assist me .

my expectation is to print only `HHHH` when office and address are present in sentence if not it should print `ZZZZ` .

Comment: you're only looking at `group(0)`. look at `group(1)` instead

Comment: You can use `/(?<=\boffice ) *[a-zA-z]+(?= +address\b)/` to extract `" HHHH"`. You will have to strip any leading spaces from the string returned. Here there is one because there are two spaces between `"office"` and `"HHHH"`, and Python does not support variable-length lookbehinds and does not out-of-the box support `\K`. The word breaks (`\b`) prevent matches on, for example, `"interoffice"` or `"addressing"`. [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xENir0/2/).